# Problem with start Daemontools services

Tags: daemontools

I created directorys with structure:
`/service/<nameservice>/run`

executed command:

```
sudo svc -dx /service/*
```

fail: svc: warning: unable to control /service/httpadapter: supervise not running

What cause of problem?

Comment: There's far too little information in the question to answer that.  You haven't mentioned what operating system you are running and what software you are running.  Answers vary greatly from Mewburn `rc` through van Smoorenburg `inittab` and upstart to systemd, and according to who packaged up daemontools for you (not that you've told us whether you are using pre-packaged daemontools).

Answer (score -2):

Problem was solved. Run:

```
 csh -cf '/command/svscanboot &'
```

and use `exec` command in script.

Comment: [This has long since been superseded](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/inittab-is-history.html#svscanboot), and is a poor choice on many modern operating systems.